# Joomla upload of custom template

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a template, that I configured according to upload to Joomla. I have tested this offline in my local Wamp server, here i worked fine. My template folder contain a CSS folder containing CSS files used in PHP index file and an image folder that contains all images used.
The problem that I'm facing is when I upload the template it opens the index but CSS and images are not working. I have two questions here:

1. how can I see the folders uploaded.
2. how do CSS and images work on the index?

Comment: can you please provide the code you're using in the index.php?

Comment: Did you upload it as an extension zipfile? If yes, did you reference the css and images folder in the manifest file?

Comment: Most probably you need to change the actual paths to CSS and image files in index.php

Answer (score 1):

1) Goto Media Manger , There you can browswe the folders like a tree structure.

2) You may be suffering a case sensitivity issue. In Localhost folder names and file names are **case insensitive**. But in Server all files names and folder names are **case sensitive**.

Verify your path include code and folder name , and make sure all are in same case.

Comment: Case sensitivity is not a case of localhost/remote server, but Windows/other OS. Windows does ignore case, while all other (especially Linux) don't.

Answer (score 0):

Bewlow points may solve your query:

1)Check the actual path of the image/css which u given CSS.

Path: yourweb.com/images

2) Set the folders permission to "777" or "755"

3)   Test in brwser yourweb.com/images/exampleimage.jpg

wheather image is present or not?

Answer (score 0):

1. First login to your Joomla admin dashboard
2. Then go to 'Extensions -> Manage -> Install'
3. Find 'Extension package file' and choose or select which template file you want to upload
4. Finally click on 'Upload & Install' button to upload your template.

See example screenshot below

[See How to upload custom Joomla Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayt1J.jpg)